# Getting server error 500 when moving wordpress to different Apache module

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, windows-server-2012-r2

I moved all of our databases to a 32-bit MySQL to 64-bit and also upgraded PHP/Apache at the same time.  Both web servers are still configured on the machine.

So if I bring up new Apache/PHP/MySQL - everything works.  I can do a new wordpress install, run PHP apps, all good.  When I transfer my files over to new doc root and my database files I get error 500 whenever trying to bring up a page (even directly).

I have taken the database out of the mix because I can run old Apache/PHP and point it to new MySQL and the sites run fine.  So I am guessing this has to do with some kind of mod rewrite setting... but it doesn't make since that a new WP install works and on that install I can change permalink structure.

Let me know if you need any more info.

Log file info:

> [18-Jun-2017 17:51:41 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a
>   member function importFromArray() on null in
>   E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-content\themes\time\drone\dronetheme.class.php:2
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-content\themes\time\inc\options.php(56): DroneTheme->addThemeFeature('favicon', Array)
>   #1 E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-content\themes\time\functions.php(415): require('E:\apache2...')
>   #2 E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-content\themes\time\drone\dronetheme.class.php(2):
>   Time->onSetupOptions(Object(DroneThemeOptionsGroup))
>   #3 E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): DroneTheme->actionAfterSetupTheme('')
>   #4 E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
>   #5 E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
>   #6 E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-settings.php(433): do_action('after_setup_the...')
>   #7 E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-config.php(78): require_once('E:\apache2...')
>    #8 E:\apache2\h in E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-content\themes\time\drone\dronetheme.class.php
>   on line 2

It seems that I might not have an extension enabled but I went one for one across my old install.

I have new version of Apache running stand alone from old.  I can turn on old version of Apache/PHP and everything works fine with same files and database.  So there has to be a config difference but I can't see it.

Comment: 500 = internal server error. This is most likely a PHP-error. Check your error log to see what the actual error message is. You said that you _"upgraded"_ Apache/PHP, but then you say _"Both web servers are still configured on the machine"_? Did you upgrade or install a new version next to it?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - updated with PHP error log.  It is basically the same message every time.  Like I said, fresh install works fine... using old Apache/PHP is fine...

Comment: _"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function importFromArray() on null in E:\apache2\htdocs\smart\wp-content\themes\time\drone\dronetheme.class.php:2"_ Seems like the error occurs in a theme file. Have you tried a fresh WP install with this theme?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Will add theme over to the test site I created and see what happens...  Still makes no sense that it works fine with new DB and old Apache/PHP.

Comment: It makes perfect sense if you're using an old PHP-version (5.x) on the old server and a newer PHP-version (7.x) on the new server. There's a bunch of breaking changes between those versions. If it's a bought theme (and it still isn't working when you test on a new install), I would contact the developers...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - great... thanks for the heads up on that.   The main reason for Apache/PHP upgrades was the 64 bit so guess I could downgrade PHP to v5 64 bit...